# Orchard Menu items type inside a Theme

Tags: c#, orchardcms

scenario : we have a bunch of themes which and depending on the navigation inside a specific theme we want to create a new Menu item type to fill the theme navigation needs .

Example : a theme which include a Menus (Parents) that has no links . inside each parent there is items (sub menus ) which include an action link ...

we'd like to create a Menu item  type for each theme , so once activated the menu type will be included in the admin navigation .

> is it possible to create those menu item types inside the theme itself not in a module ?

Answer (score 1):

So long as your theme has a project file you can implement the `IMenuProvider` interface to attach menu items to a menu.

This answer has an example implementation: [Creating a navigation menu item in Orchard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29235508/creating-a-navigation-menu-item-in-orchard/48672441#48672441)

Comment: i v implemented IMenuProvider and for some  reason the project file never called . ( i v activated my theme )

Comment: Is your theme a project, with a .csproj file?

Comment: Yes its generated with a project /IncludeProject:true

Comment: but my services from the theme does not seems to be reachable